# Error while installation of PyQt5 in python 3.8.3

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5

I have been trying to download PyQt5 but it keeps showing an error. I tried python version 3.10 but it also gave me an error.

Here is the error which I get-

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/27/fd81188a35f37be9b3b4c2db1654d9439d1418823916fe702ac3658c9c41/PyQt5-5.15.6.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kl6ymrd8\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'sip >=6.4, <7' 'PyQt-builder >=1.9, <2'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (121 lines):
  Collecting sip<7,>=6.4
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/c1/9ac5596c10f6ce28abc1849ed1b6299b3953af0b6ff21e227024991a517e/sip-6.5.1.tar.gz
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
  Collecting PyQt-builder<2,>=1.9
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/55/db354bd9dfa613c8f8f6ecb81617caefdfb3e77befba098f8e14ed95e385/PyQt_builder-1.12.2-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting setuptools (from sip<7,>=6.4)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/5b/3d92b9f0f7ca1645cba48c080b54fe7d8b1033a4e5720091d1631c4266db/setuptools-60.10.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting packaging (from sip<7,>=6.4)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/8e/8de486cbd03baba4deef4142bd643a3e7bbe954a784dc1bb17142572d127/packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting toml (from sip<7,>=6.4)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/6f/7120676b6d73228c96e17f1f794d8ab046fc910d781c8d151120c3f1569e/toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 (from packaging->sip<7,>=6.4)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/c1/23fd82ad3121656b585351aba6c19761926bb0db2ebed9e4ff09a43a3fcc/pyparsing-3.0.7-py3-none-any.whl
  Building wheels for collected packages: sip
    Building wheel for sip (PEP 517): started
    Building wheel for sip (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6lmjb9iq'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ihnr9js0\sip
    Complete output (89 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\abstract_builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\abstract_project.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\api.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\argument_parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\bindings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\buildable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\configurable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\distutils_builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\installable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\project.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\pyproject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\py_versions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\setuptools_builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\distinfo
    copying sipbuild\distinfo\distinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\distinfo
    copying sipbuild\distinfo\main.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\distinfo
    copying sipbuild\distinfo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\distinfo
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module
    copying sipbuild\module\abi_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module
    copying sipbuild\module\main.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module
    copying sipbuild\module\module.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module
    copying sipbuild\module\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\tools
    copying sipbuild\tools\build.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\tools
    copying sipbuild\tools\install.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\tools
    copying sipbuild\tools\sdist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\tools
    copying sipbuild\tools\wheel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\tools
    copying sipbuild\tools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\tools
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\apiversions.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\array.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\array.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\bool.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\descriptors.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\int_convertors.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\LICENSE -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\LICENSE-GPL2 -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\LICENSE-GPL3 -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\MANIFEST.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\objmap.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\pyproject.toml -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\qtlib.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\README.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\setup.cfg.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\setup.py.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sip.h.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sip.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sip.rst.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sipint.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\siplib.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\threads.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\voidptr.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\array.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\array.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\bool.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\descriptors.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\int_convertors.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\LICENSE -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\LICENSE-GPL2 -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\LICENSE-GPL3 -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\MANIFEST.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\objmap.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\pyproject.toml -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\README.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\setup.cfg.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\setup.py.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sip.h.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sip.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sip.rst.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sipint.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\siplib.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\threads.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\voidptr.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    running build_ext
    building 'sipbuild.code_generator' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for sip
    Running setup.py clean for sip
  Failed to build sip
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for sip which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
  WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 22.0.4 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kl6ymrd8\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'sip >=6.4, <7' 'PyQt-builder >=1.9, <2' Check the logs for full command output.
```

My python version is 3.8

I cant change my python version because I will have to install a lot of modules and some errors can come in installing those modules also.

Comment: Read the error message: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

Comment: try upgrade pip: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and then `python -m pip install pyqt5`

Comment: Thank You very much, it worked. I added that 'Please help me and thank you' because stackoverflows won't let me upload the question saying I had too less words. It honestly feels stupid because I tried to do everything except upgrading pip to solve my problem.